# Laptop was stolen, they tried to log into my facebook from their location on my laptop

Tags: passwords

Can I get some advice on what I should do next? Laptop was stolen yesterday and they tried to log in my facebook today like 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Since this is tagged "passwords", I suppose you have already changed your passwords?

Comment: +1 to @S.L.Barth - Perhaps if you could provide more detail as to what sort of guidance you're looking for (i.e.: asset recovery, social media account security, etc.) we could better answer the question.  Right now, it's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Michael - as @Iszi says, you'll need to provide us with more information. As it stands this isn't a very useful question.

Comment: Immediately contact law enforcement and inform them of this. They can likely help you.

Answer (score 16):

Although you did not mention in which country you are in, it is very likely that stealing is a crime there. So you should go to the police.

Answer (score 11):

First thing: **change your passwords**. Start with your **email** (since this is the gateway to many of your other accounts via password recovery). Keep in mind that the thief may have a fair amount of information about you, so make sure the new passwords are not easy to guess.

Then, for accounts that support it (e.g. Gmail), force-logout any other sessions that are active. (E.g. on Gmail there's a link in the bottom right corner that says something like "Open in 1 other location *Details*" -- click on the details link and use the button that logs out other sessions.) It may be helpful to an investigation if you record the IP address that the other session is using.

Then report the theft to local police.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, GMail/LogMeIn tracks IP address usage on your accounts.

Luckily, Facebook has the same capability - go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions and it will display the locations, OS, browser - and most important, IP information of all the sessions open in your account. IANAL, but I'm pretty sure (as also mentioned) if you provide the IP address to law enforcement under the charge of stolen property, you'll more than likely see justice, and your laptop.

**EDIT: Didn't realize this question is old - hopefully you've gotten your laptop back. :P**

Answer (score 1):

This may be hindsight at this point, but I use LogMeIn on all my(the company's) PC's. Two of these were stolen. Luckily LogMeIn keeps track of all ipaddresses that are used by each PC. I have submitted the two ipaddresses to the police, and have had the two laptops returned to me.

Think back to remember what you had on the laptop. I know gmail keeps up with ipaddresses as well. Maybe you too had something on the laptop to help you find it.